# Как запустить функцию в потоке и далее и пользоваться данными, которые она возвращает?

Tags: python

Всем привет. Столкнулась с проблемой. Есть две функции. Одна отдает список статей, и на основе этих статей идет передача в другую функцию каждой из статей.

```
class get_list(Theared):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
    def run(self):
        #получени статьи
        #list - массив со статьями
        self.list.append(list)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.list)
     

class read_list(Theared):
    def __init__(self, p_list):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.list = p_list
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        #идет работа со статьей.

if __name__=="__main__":
    i=1
    while i>0:
        finallList = get_list()
        if finallList :
            for one_list in finallList:
                read_list(one_list)
                i=i+1
```

Но проблема в том , что мне нужно проверять наличие статей например каждые 5 сек, и параллельно должна отрабатывать функция read_list.
Пыталась сделать тоже через класс с Thread функцию get_list, но тогда скрипт падает в ошибку

```
TypeError: 'get_list' object is not iterable
```

Есть у кого-то идея как сделать ?

Comment: Начните с того, что проверьте что функции работают как вам нужно и возвращают нужные объекты правильных типов без потоков. Если это у вас работает, то покажите эти функции, чтоб было понятно, какая логика без потоков. Я вопрос не понимаю до конца, но судя по ошибке все выглядит так, что потоки тут ни при чем, а просто ваша функция работает не так как вы хотите/ожидаете.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, функция у  меня нормально работает. Ошибку я получаю, если get_list() превращаю в класс такой же,как и read_list, для того  чтобы функцию запускать в потоке. Но на выходе мне нужно получить список статей, а я получаю данную ошибку

Comment: Об этом и речь. Когда у вас функция `get_list()` возвращает список, то по нему можно итерировать. А когда вы ее превратили в объект - то по нему итерировать нельзя - об этом и говорит сообщение об ошибке. Нужно реализовать [протокол итератора](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/23_oop_special_methods/iterable_iterator.html) в этом объекте

Comment: @RomanKonoval, я испарила код используя __iter__, но у меня все равно нет итерации никакой.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать модуль queue

```
import queue
q=queue.Queue(2)
q.empty()
#True
q.full()
#False
q.put(1)
q.get()
#1
```

Который отлично сочетается с асинхронными вызовами

Answer (score 0):

Я понял задачу так, что нужно чтоб:

1. один поток (в примере ниже это `ListProducer`) генерировал значения
2. главный поток итерирует по списку ожидая, если значений нет
3. для каждого значения, запускается отдельный поток (в примере `ItemConsumer`) для его обработки

Вот код:

```
from time import sleep
from queue import Empty, Queue
from threading import Thread

class ListProducer(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListProducer, self).__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.stop = False
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.queue.put(i)
            print(f"producer: creating {i}")
            sleep(0.5)
        self.stop = True
        print("producer: done")

    def __iter__(self):
        while not self.stop:
            try:
                yield self.queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            except Empty:
                pass


class ItemConsumer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, item):
        super(ItemConsumer, self).__init__()
        self.item = item
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print(f"consumer: processing {self.item}")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"consumer: processed {self.item}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    producer = ListProducer()
    for item in producer:
        ItemConsumer(item)
    print("main: done")
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста такой вопрос. в классе ItemConsumer нужно,чтобы каждая итерация из ListProducer была как отельный поток. А сейчас это как один поток. как исправить это?

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. В коде, который в ответе, на каждый элемент (итерацию) запускается отдельный поток в `ItemConsumer`.

Comment: Еще раз - этот код создает по потоку на элемент. Каждый вызов конструктора `ItemConsumer` запускает новый поток, можете вывести идентификатор потока в `run`: `print("consumer {}: processing {}".format(self.ident, self.item))`. Почему вы решили, что один поток? Какие ваши доказательства? Может у вас в `run` делаются какие-то интенсивные вычисления, т.е. у вас CPU-bound задача? Тогда вы столкнулись с GIL, а именно с тем, что в python два потока не могут в принципе исполняться параллельно.

Comment: если в очередь добавляется не одно число,а массив данных. Например [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]. То тогда в ItemConsumer передается не элемент массива,а полностью сам массив. И поток в ItemConsumer должен работать с элементом того массива

Comment: Конкретно по этому вопросу - сделайте еще один (т.е. вложеный) цикл по элементам массива. Но только это противоречит тому, что вы просили в первом комментарии (` каждая итерация из ListProducer была как отельный поток`). Я не понимаю, что вам нужно. и сдаюсь. Надеюсь, кто-то сможет помочь.